# Конфликт зависимостей EmguCV

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2017, emgucv, зависимости

Скачал библиотеку `EmguCV`. Все делаю по мануалу, однако возникла следующая непонятная для меня ошибка:

> Ошибка    CS0433  Тип "VideoCapture" существует как в
>   "Emgu.CV.World.NetStandard1_4, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral,
>   PublicKeyToken=null", так и в "Emgu.CV.World, Version=3.4.1.2976,
>   Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null"

Чем вызвана данная ошибка?

Comment: Удалите один из пакетов из файла конфигурации. Чтобы он знал откуда брать `VideoCapture`. Просто он не знает откуда взять, так как `VideoCapture` есть и там и там. `Emgu.CV.World, Version=3.4.1.2976` - вот эту оставьте

Comment: Извиняюсь, но я не силен в emgucv да и в целом тоже только начал.Что мне нужно сделать конкретнее...

Comment: Давненько не работал с такими приложениями... должен быть файл конфигурации `config` - там будут прописаны пакеты, вот оттуда и нужно один убрать. Или через управление пакетами проекта в самой VS зайти и посмотреть, что установлено и ненужное убрать.

Comment: Пробую...Отпишусь..